# JAVA: Is there a shorter way of printing out Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, sequence, fibonacci

Basically, I would like to know if there is a shorter way of printing out the Fibonacci numbers from 0 - 100.

What I have done is probably very basic, but here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number[] = new int[100];

    number[0] = 0;
    number[1] = 1;

    int sum1 = number[0] + number[0];
    int sum2 = sum1 + number[1];
    int sum3 = sum1 + sum2;
    int sum4 = sum2 + sum3;
    int sum5 = sum3 + sum4;
    int sum6 = sum4 + sum5;

    System.out.println(sum1);
    System.out.println(sum2);
    System.out.println(sum3);
    System.out.println(sum4);
    System.out.println(sum5);
    System.out.println(sum6);

}
```

And I would be doing this up until 100. But I'm sure there is a quicker way of doing this. How?

Comment: have you ever heard of Google?

Comment: define shorter: code length or runtime?

Comment: Google founds e.g. this: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Fibonacci.java.html

Comment: http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_(Java)

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Java

Comment: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/13flow/Fibonacci.java.html

Comment: What you need to learn are [loops](https://www.google.com/search?q=loop+java)

Comment: The way you are coding it seems a much quicker way is to **work out with pen and paper.**

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  As you may have noticed from the comments, our community encourages using external resources first.  At that point, if you get stuck, feel free to post your issue and we can help you work through it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop. This example uses BigInteger as the number quickly become too large for `long`.

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.ZERO, b = BigInteger.ONE;
System.out.println(1);
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    BigInteger c = a.add(b);
    System.out.println(c);
    a = b;
    b = c;
}
```

prints after a couple of seconds finally

420269270299515438 ... many, many digits deleted ... 9669707537501

Note: you don't need to memorize all the previous values, just the last two.

Answer (score 0):

Standard way to do this is by recursion:

Have a look at this simple snippet, which returns the fibonacci number at position a:

```
public static long fib(int a){
      if (a==1||a==2) return 1;
      else return fib(a-1)+fib(a-2);
    }
```

Comment: In Java the number of calls is equal to the answer making this a simple, but very slow solution.

Comment: Can you tell me the 10,000,000th Fibonacci number this way?

Comment: Use memoization for an efficient solution.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders - memoization only helps if you repeatedly call the same operation. In this case, it would cut the execution time in half, at a cost of O(N) memory. In addition to the O(N) stack frames used to handle recursion (because this is not tail-call optimizable as written).

Comment: @parsifal When cast to `long` the 10 millionth number is `8644293272739028509` (This is just the lowest 64-bits of course)

Comment: @Peter - I trust you used the solution that you posted, and not the recursive solution.

Comment: @parsifal Even using BigInteger was too slow.  I changed it to use plain `long` instead. ;)

Answer (score 0):

google search ftw!... wasn't even a minute searching

```
int[] fibonacci = new int[25+1];
fibonacci[1] = 1;
fibonacci[2] = 1;
for ( int i = 3; i < fibonacci.length; i++ )
{
fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-2] + fibonacci[i-1];
}
```

Comment: I would hope that searching was quick, there are at least 4 implementations already posted in the comments.

Comment: there is some explicit way to do it but it's very complicated so it's easier to do it recursivly

Answer (score 0):

Print number < 100 with n=11

```
public int getFib(int n){
  if(n==0) return 0;
  else if(n==1) return 1;
 else{
 int temp=getFib(n-1)+getFib(n-2);
 return temp;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't want to use the recursive way..
Here is the iterative...

```
public class Fib2 {

public static int fib(int n, int a, int b)
{
if (n==0)
    {
System.out.print("1x +");
    return a;
    }
else
    {
System.out.print("2x +");
    return fib(n-1,b,a+b);
    }
}
public static void main(String arg[])
{
System.out.println(fib(0,1,1));
}
}
```

Comment: You should probably learn what [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) is, and how it differs from [iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing).

Answer (score 0):

Well, 100 isn't one of the Fibonacci numbers, however if we include 144, then this is a nice succinct example:

```
class F
{
    public static void main( final String[] a )
    {
        int a = 1, b = 1;
        for ( ; b < 145; a = b + (b = a) )
            System.out.println( b );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this without arrays here is the way to do it. Just change 20 to 100. This is the way I had to do it for an assignment and it is simple to understand for those still learning.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int number1 = 1;
    int number2 = 1;
    int count;
    int fib;
    System.out.print(number1 + " " + number2 + " ");
    for(count = 3; count <= 20; count++)
    {
        fib = number1 + number2;
        number1 = number2;
        number2 = fib;
        System.out.print(fib + " ");
    }
}
```